# It's possible to rewrite submitticket.php being submit-ticket in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to know how to change current URL

```
http://domain.com/submitticket.php
```

To be

```
http://domain.com/submit-ticket/
```

Let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^submitticket/?$ /submit-ticket/
```

If you have no other things in you URL

```
RewriteRule ^submitticket/(.*)$ /submit-ticket/$1
```

If you have following information

Comment: Thanks M'vy. I tried both and return to `The requested URL /submit-ticket.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: Of course you need to have an index.php in a directory called submit-ticket an apache configured to server index.php when asking for directories. Or to write a rewrite rule to do that. Or maybe you want the user to type submit-ticket and get served the file you have in submitticket instead? Then you shall inverse the rewrite rule.